# Is my current approach to force outgoing packets through a bonded interface as the gw device appropriate?

Tags: linux, networking

I have two NIC cards with 4 ports each on Redhat 6.1.

When the application comes up, it creates a bonded interface with one port from each NIC (example: `eth1` and `eth4`), and assigns a virtual IP to that interface.  Once this interface is up, all the packets from this machine should go through the bonded interface.

To achieve this currently, I'm changing the default gw device name to the bonded interface using the `ip route` command: `ip route replace default via 10.3.2.1 dev INT-BOND`.

When stopping the application, we bring down the bonded interface and change the default gw device name back to `eth0`.

The problem with my approach is if someone brings down the bonded interface (`ifdown`), then it removes the default gw.

I need confirmation that my currently working approach is fine to proceed with going forward; otherwise, should I go with modifications to the `iptables/ip rules`, or are there any better suggestions?

Comment: This definitely wants to be on http://serverfault.com/ . Sadly, it's too old to migrate.